# How to use pgrep inside bash script correctly?

Tags: bash, process

I'm running a GUI program called [zeal](http://zealdocs.org/)(compiled from src) and add a script(zeal.sh) for the executable:

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep zeal &>/dev/null; then
    printf "already on\n"
else
    ~/tools/zeal/zeal/zeal &>/dev/null &
fi
```

The strange thing is that when I run this script like `/path/to/zeal.sh`, it always tells "already on", while with `bash /path/to/zeal.sh` it correctly decides whether the process is running or not.

I also checked other GUI programs(like firefox) with similar scripts and they work fine.

So how can this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the direct call makes the script name the command name, see

```
cat /proc/$PID/comm
```

That causes `pgrep` to match. If called via `bash` then the command name is "bash".

Use

```
pgrep --exact zeal
```

instead.

Comment: The `--exact` flag does not work on `macOS` but you can use a **regex pattern** like this: `[$]> pgrep '^zeal$'`

Answer (score 6):

The long option `--exact` proposed in Hauke's answer didn't work on some systems. You can use the equivalent short option `-x` instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -x "zeal" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Running"
else
    echo "Stopped"
fi
```

Comment: And if you get the error 'pgrep unary operator expected', make sure to leave the square brackets off of the 'if' statement. Common rookie mistake. :)